# Displaying images from associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get my miniatures view to display all associated photos from the collections model.

My sample miniature has two photos but the following code gives an error "undefined method `photo' for #".

```
<% @miniature.collections(:photo).each do |photo| %>
  <%= image_tag @miniature.collections.photo.url(:medium) %>
<% end %>
```

I think that the relationships are all correct though because rails console works fine with them and the following code shows the first image, twice.

```
<% @miniature.collections(:photo).each do |photo| %>
    <%= image_tag @miniature.collections.first.photo.url(:medium) %>
    <% end %>
```

Equally I can swap out first for last and show the 2nd image twice. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing a huge amount about your associations, I'm relatively sure you want to use the instance variable that you instantiated in the `each` loop. That would look like something to the effect of:

```
<% @miniature.collections(:photo).each do |collection| %>
  <% if !collection.photo.url(:medium).nil? %>
    <%= image_tag collection.photo.url(:medium) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Using `@miniature.collections.first.photo.url(:medium)` would display the first image of the collection once for each photo in the collection. Likely this is not what you want.

Comment: That sounds great but then it says undefined method `url'. Collection belongs_to Miniature and Miniature has_many :collections.

Comment: Ahh, maybe I misunderstood your question. Try instead what I put in the edit.

Comment: Ahaha! YES! I get it. It's the collection that is the repeating thing, not the photo. We instance the collection and use that to show each photo? Brilliant.

Comment: Is there any easy way to tweak it so that it only tries to load the photo if there is one? I have instances where it is loading 3 broken images and one image because not all collections have images. Something like collection.where.photo? or similar?

Comment: I would probably just use an if statement. It's the simplest. I'll throw that into the answer as well.

Comment: Ah great. I was trying to do it with where. and ? and it wasn't working. Thanks so much.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. Shouldn't be if it is not nil? I'll keep working at it. I'm sure I can get it to work.

Comment: Make sure you note the !

Comment: Yeah for some reason that doesn't have any effect. I've been playing around with it, using TRY and TRUE and FALSE but can't get it to work at all. It still renders broken images where it should show nothing.

Comment: Well it depends on what you're storing. If collection.photo.url(:medium) contains a url to an image, and the image isn't there, it'll render a broken image. If you have to check, you should use File.exist?(collection.photo.url(:medium)) in the if statement as well (with an 'and' between the two clauses).

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I still can't get this to work. It either renders absolutely nothing or it renders broken images regardless of the if. I'll come back to it later in the project.